# File size is shown to be empty even when it has data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am using Cloudera CDH4.3.1 version of Hadoop and I moved a file of size 1Kb to HDFS, but its size in HDFS is shown to be 0Kb?

Why is this happening? Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: You are seeing 0KB while file copying ? or after file is copied ? How are moving the file ?

Comment: After copying does it have any data?

Comment: After copy it shows as 0KB, but file has some contents.

Comment: How you are checking the file size, can you post your command

Comment: i am using ls command